# How to extract only Time from a DateTime field in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, datetime, oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried `To_Timestamp` and other methods for SQL Developer but only this one worked fine for me.

```
Select To_Number(To_Char(DateTime_FieldName, 'HH24'))
    || ':' || to_number(to_char(DateTime_FieldName, 'MI'))
    || ':' ||to_number(to_char(DateTime_FieldName, 'SS'))
from TABLE_NAME
```

Is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Assuming your goal is to generate a string representing the time (which is what the query you posted returns despite the extraneous `to_number` calls)

```
SELECT to_char( <<column_name>>, 'HH24:MI:SS' )
  FROM table_name
```

If you want to return a different data type, you'd need to tell us what data type you want to return.  If, for example, you really want to return an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`

```
SELECT numtodsinterval( <<column name>> - trunc(<<column name>>), 'day' )
  FROM table_name
```