# How to extract only time from '0/0/0000 10:23:56 AM'?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, to-date, to-char

I am having date as `0/0/0000 10:23:56 AM` in a column.

I have tried with `TO_CHAR(column_dt,'hh24:mm:ss')` and `TO_CHAR(column_dt,'hh:mm:ss pm')`, but both are returning `00:00:00` and `00:00:00 00` respectively.

Can any one please help me out ?

Comment: Following link will help you:
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104414/how-to-extract-only-time-from-a-datetime-field-in-oracle-sql-developer

Comment: What datatype is the column column_dt, is it a DATE or VARCHAR2?

Comment: `0/0/0000` is an invalid date, and Oracle won't let you store that. You can't possibly have that date.

Comment: I have this date ...The datatype is DATE

Comment: If the column is defined as `DATE` then it can't possible have the value `0/0/0000`

Answer (score 2):

The "date" `0/0/0000 10:23:56 AM` is not a valid date (minimum day and month is 01 and year must be different from 0) so i'm guessing that the column is varchar. If you want to extract the time from that string you can use something like this:

```
select SUBSTR('0/0/0000 10:23:56 AM', 10, 8) time,
SUBSTR('0/0/0000 10:23:56 AM', 10, 2) hh,
SUBSTR('0/0/0000 10:23:56 AM', 13, 2) MI,
SUBSTR('0/0/0000 10:23:56 AM', 16, 2) ss
  FROM DUAL
```

Comment: The data type of that column is DATE. And I have this record.

Comment: OK but you still can use `SUBSTR` to extract what you need right?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Yourdatecolumn, 114)
```

Comment: Add your date column..ok let me take this more simple use SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 114) try this now.

Comment: That's invalid for Oracle

Comment: I have added the column. After that only it is showing the same. ( it's an oracle db)...for Jayanti